# status code 500 while fetching Data from MongoDB using FastAPI

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I'm writing a FastAPI endpoint from My MongoDB, when I try to fetch all the transactions in the collection I encounter code 500: internal server Error
Here is my code :

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pymongo import MongoClient 
from bson import json_util
import json

app = FastAPI()

# MongoDB connection details
mongo_url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"  
client = MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = client.banking  
collection = db.transaction_data 

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

# all transactions
@app.get("/transactions")
async def get_transactions():
    try:
        transactions = collection.find()
        
        # Transform the cursor to a list of dictionaries
        transaction_list = [transaction for transaction in transactions]

        # Return the list of dictionaries
        return transaction_list
        
    except:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Transactions not found")
```

[Swagger docs screenshot of the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqRtw.png)
How can I go about this issue since testing my Mongo its well connected and has data in it, FastAPI also works well independently only issue is when fetching from a collection

Comment: The console where you're running your application should show a stack trace which indicates what the issue is - a 500 error means that something went wrong in your code - usually that something unexpected happened. That error message will help you narrow down what the issue can be.

Comment: You must copy in your question the information that the error console gives you so that we can help you, as mentioned above. From now on I think it may be a problem with the id. But copy the console logs and I'll give you a hand